# Google Apps Script: 403 in simple UrlFetchApp.fetch

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, google-apps-script

I have the following Python code that runs fine from my computer:

```
>>> from requests import get
>>> response = get("https://fiis.com.br/btal11/")
>>> response
<Response [403]>
>>> response = get("https://fiis.com.br/btal11/", headers={'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
>>> response
<Response [200]>
```

If I simply add a user-agent header, I'm able to get the html page content. However, with the equivalent JS code on google Apps Script that doesn't work:

```
function GORDON(input) {
  var url = "https://fiis.com.br/btal11/";
  var options = {
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    headers: {"User-agent": "Mozilla/5.0"},
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  console.log(response.getContentText());
  //var something = HtmlService.parse(response.getContentText());
}
```

and the result seems to be a challenge from Cloudflare to be solved:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title>Just a moment...</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <link href="/cdn-cgi/styles/challenges.css" rel="stylesheet">
    

</head>
<body class="no-js">
    <div class="main-wrapper" role="main">
    <div class="main-content">
        <h1 class="zone-name-title h1">
            <img class="heading-favicon" src="/favicon.ico" alt="Icon for fiis.com.br"
                 onerror="this.onerror=null;this.parentNode.removeChild(this)">
            fiis.com.br
        </h1>
        <h2 class="h2" id="challenge-running">
            Checking if the site connection is secure
        </h2>
        <noscript>
            <div id="challenge-error-title">
                <div class="h2">
                    <span class="icon-wrapper">
                        <div class="heading-icon warning-icon"></div>
                    </span>
                    <span id="challenge-error-text">
                        Enable JavaScript and cookies to continue
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </noscript>
        <div id="trk_jschal_js" style="display:none;background-image:url('/cdn-cgi/images/trace/managed/nojs/transparent.gif?ray=79c3f9c65b60e3b6')"></div>
        <div id="challenge-body-text" class="core-msg spacer">
            fiis.com.br needs to review the security of your connection before proceeding.
        </div>
        <form id="challenge-form" action="/btal11/?__cf_chl_f_tk=1lWKKYirqW.UmES1h5ANk6aNER4buUV9BvandjshiQU-1676861855-0-gaNycGzNCHs" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
            <input type="hidden" name="md" value="vA5q0MLK_A04uFcQqCyCa20MICLT.o_hZCm87QeOsEc-1676861855-0-Ab6XuJyj-1RtGxhMzcfJQ2E1vrHaAOzs987bM2ZpxqFwZvWYvUEnID4JOSO1iJLQDPqYPPzX-AwcdroRh5CKZ2UP4_o_uqOfOeYMVZJo1S4iqBZ3loTopwRBpVHtAADxvebnNBvP_HyStPDyJH0VkGGHwcBpjJsmv-duU8lhq7z9ex0TS-wNsyNhp4eoM23Uwzi30418XhWvNqoK66sEcrN6vaZW8EJEGFfxW2LDf-R9ZoYUay2xt4Xgcwz17nDgEWeGlR_L-S5RvonpDTBnk5ujbFc_hdwX7Y39NdeIDLTlTCtudzHHEsK0hhbZjHVL7xl4YwkgxKoLaL-URi59VSdHMNcxlHZNt65EWGwS_gXhXG7BFX74CI-EgVo-138F_E9KyWgWz2kL2C4RYG-fcRHEMsYUZznCznaRm4CipklQIGrg1TzLb8GmB25HhjZM-BgKMprLPWJ2jCJ_Yw5KxurVebXuzinZt43H_5klyYd3Of0TwBnTjVMmDbdWsQaQds7PWHi1qq7fXVATS9MzHzZiaY7VmLjdkMWizlMIAmBafYqltGgh8dEZy3sPom6zbj38YGuOxF6gJWrx1tBGm_Kdm15E3gZqgKpmyRuXPDb-a6m0ncJK41sn6XUxUxM-2QuvV1OyAylzTyVderxsqKGH1VJlHcRVUxVyAldAgzMT4SHhH3kcN0CF3cPH9bj1yrw29rXel4ZKowdCYfzRgVJJxdmaz6MTqeEdoj9eXk9h_hfOS1xYImhsCKD1r7SFsmNx2-awD3il9esnD-OR7NwuUg9CruUOBeOnUUgZEg88_l_-B5TYEHARh9Vecg6KVru0XxlaZU2x42gE8vfiKcUKWbNykHFgXFYSwwqwc6zLtF_1UVi76EA0RTX0dITNU-dyXbSRn7HUT8UJojrc5uohnsO5u1smAz9JH7cGJGiZABVaVyKxVIfVQRIPXkbfndrUY_9M5TS0Ms6LLYfozjEGVbC6SegE-FzQEGvJeTHrQz2nA4PM_m3by4L283EJDHk3jnd23_CpM6coZrQxLlyrpAxOzi3lx91cppJONKQd0QMJNaTY6j5URnx2uO8Uto1tbeXZ3lKKheIuYfxBECzuALkPqNqB3pbdm3H6TXPSrpBmqWHPB7yqSowbkQN5qHFePDdg6DBuH40Hm4NgONvkVMmD_D4r8HyJ58-GK4gDF_bmWJjgyLB5pMsxCcGZm50u9bS7f-eHDMyGTYdhlOzU6tnJs3-B54m2ph65RNPgkYqg3TDFDHc1GDM61vhxj2QFAJY_crvxYhd6mAr1C--fk38rs1f_LX42Uqt1rcZCEZXr5eHFivIuAmDlSl-8iz0C8Y2K9M0fUS-fid6dcYuK5BHWb9FTJ5lNWkRfEWIXyV-YhWdWkB85_NbPnPOOgDiNzPlCEzUN-AkzUFjFhEIu1k6goZUQXXujthhQta0NTG0T0B4aD3DB-k5ihYILF_w6vDhAZcAFz-TcR4t_TuvoHkGnlwwC354-1Hcb0IPdcrZIXb_8_PpIKRSHQeCErlzLYJfg0ZUobNbSVC6b6p15uXzITqX5FCoTIGNUWuWqiCYLBvcWcTBbAevpxQDLDrQfM351ZQUrcT5aeET6SeWLZftKhAZeHdiAc8KK_iw6jUpxrB4v2oGZAlU372wBIEZ0eQYQhMwJnm-PMODd3BodqE5HJe0Sc7wnUyjTT3Rxwv06Luv0-8CfswblPIYq7Mwx771ZXXPZmQyrepQ1-bBntEsvFgGI4jyPu8RKHuq8H8kdtLsj_t747dkdRq9zmXGIcCcTh09Vj-sTKHZPIHh396ljgzlVJ7k_nWX8BCHibRj3kUtnDhJarkzlobqb985ZNSybspZKlbG8f3qIWdo1wa1-Bo002tNWyElRcDt_xwXuneDTyP0qQWyX-7kKXlJFIYQ9detREaifPI1hA8fU11U2r2XzEsOLpxao18T9D9DjkvC4cGh6BsE3s8uyW06_Q5QhxvsADyW7HkZ6I72H_l6zObf9N3uKYfEy8CrcdMsS7eLXaLvxbzuNd2WuxbKu3N8AiI9D51lU8CEnSKCQa4SUzRj4f2q62HjhiG9HpT9TYRdyYPMsbb_eXUxvrA">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    (function(){
        window._cf_chl_opt={
            cvId: '2',
            cZone: 'fiis.com.br',
            cType: 'managed',
            cNounce: '97809',
            cRay: '79c3f9c65b60e3b6',
            cHash: 'fc3e1644bceb435',
            cUPMDTk: "\/btal11\/?__cf_chl_tk=1lWKKYirqW.UmES1h5ANk6aNER4buUV9BvandjshiQU-1676861855-0-gaNycGzNCHs",
            cFPWv: 'g',
            cTTimeMs: '1000',
            cMTimeMs: '0',
            cTplV: 4,
            cTplB: 'cf',
            cRq: {
                ru: 'aHR0cHM6Ly9maWlzLmNvbS5ici9idGFsMTEv',
                ra: 'TW96aWxsYS81LjAgKGNvbXBhdGlibGU7IEdvb2dsZS1BcHBzLVNjcmlwdDsgYmVhbnNlcnZlcjsgK2h0dHBzOi8vc2NyaXB0Lmdvb2dsZS5jb207IGlkOiBVQUVtZERkOHNNRzFSb0FJWGZTYnlsa2plUGwxdjhTdngwVUkp',
                rm: 'R0VU',
                d: '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',
                t: 'MTY3Njg2MTg1NS43MzUwMDA=',
                m: 'SOz4uar/pXrmGBuSQIbY9tjFx2G6zirpJv2NyzOPmIM=',
                i1: 'cIUbIpvI2YsvZRb//Yfdfw==',
                i2: 'oC3KkuH26ng8Gt/f/kKHDw==',
                zh: 'wcWWf/+obaYUptPh30e4072sXWiLjlPsWQnQS/2QxMI=',
                uh: 'bllaG+Wp51WdmfI9k7pslxqw3F1/Neha3nrwdAjxueE=',
                hh: '+MXXTc/rARCfTxK8igcq3MtDXAltL4ou2PYE97G16x4=',
            }
        };
        var trkjs = document.createElement('img');
        trkjs.setAttribute('src', '/cdn-cgi/images/trace/managed/js/transparent.gif?ray=79c3f9c65b60e3b6');
        trkjs.setAttribute('alt', '');
        trkjs.setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
        document.body.appendChild(trkjs);
        var cpo = document.createElement('script');
        cpo.src = '/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/g/orchestrate/managed/v1?ray=79c3f9c65b60e3b6';
        window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash = location.hash === '' && location.href.indexOf('#') !== -1 ? '#' : location.hash;
        window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUQuery = location.search === '' && location.href.slice(0, location.href.length - window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash.length).indexOf('?') !== -1 ? '?' : location.search;
        if (window.history && window.history.replaceState) {
            var ogU = location.pathname + window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUQuery + window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash;
            history.replaceState(null, null, "\/btal11\/?__cf_chl_rt_tk=1lWKKYirqW.UmES1h5ANk6aNER4buUV9BvandjshiQU-1676861855-0-gaNycGzNCHs" + window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash);
            cpo.onload = function() {
                history.replaceState(null, null, ogU);
            };
        }
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(cpo);
    }());
</script>


    <div class="footer" role="contentinfo">
        <div class="footer-inner">
            <div class="clearfix diagnostic-wrapper">
                <div class="ray-id">Ray ID: <code>79c3f9c65b60e3b6</code></div>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center" id="footer-text">Performance &amp; security by <a rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.cloudflare.com?utm_source=challenge&utm_campaign=m" target="_blank">Cloudflare</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I missing over here? Is there any way to bypass this challenge?

Comment: Unfortunately, in the current stage, `UrlFetchApp.fetch` of Google Apps Script cannot change the user agent. I think that this might be the reason for your current issue.

Comment: Almost that actually. It is possible to change it BUT ... google appends extra info that screws up everything. Used `http://httpbin.org/user-agent` for debugging. With python requests got simply `{'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}` as a response. But with JS, got `{"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Google-Apps-Script; beanserver; +https://script.google.com; id: UAEmdDd8sMG1RoAIXfSbylkjePl1v8Svx0UI)"
}`. All that junk appended screwed up things, and end ups blocking my request :/

Comment: Thank you for replying. When a Google Apps Script is used, such an issue occurs. For example, if you directly run your script on your browser, I think that when a dialog and sidebar are used, your goal might be able to be achieved because in this case Javascript is used for requesting. But, I'm not sure about your actual situation. So, if this was not included in your expected direction, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of @Tanaike, discovered that unfortunately Google appends junk info on user-agent header, which ends up being blocked by cloudflare. Doesn't seem to have a simple solution for now.